# How to download a file in Headless mode using UiPath?

Tags: headless-browser, uipath

I have an Open Browser activity that goes on a site, makes two clicks in order to save the file, 10 seconds delay and then closes the tab. The clicks are set to SimulateClick=True. Everything works just fine with both Native or WebDriver methods.

But I need to start the browser in Headless mode (Hidden=True in Open Browser activity) because I’m making a background automation that saves the said file. Now, in Headless mode the browser is not saving the file, it doesn’t matter which browser (edge, chrome, firefox) I’ve tried all of them, same issue. And I don’t get any error. No WebDriver error. No click activity error. Nothing.

I can’t use IE because the site doesn’t support IE anymore.

Any thoughts on how to make the browser download the file in Headless mode?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the url path to the file itself, consider using an http request activity to download the file.

You can set the Input>Endpoint property to the string containing the URL and set the Options>Resource Path to the local file path where it should be saved.

UiPath's documentation on this activity can be found [here](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/http-client)

Comment: I can't get the URL using 'get attribute'. Maybe because after I press the said button (download file type, as in: Combined, Single View PDF) appears a window that says "Please wait" and the downloading begins. So that button just triggers the downloading event I guess.
I'm trying to download a PDF from Draftable if someone heard about it.

Comment: Draftable has an API you may want to consider using?

Comment: Yes. That's how I just did it. Would've been easier with the clicks but it works just fine with all of the invoke codes and requests that I had to put into it (I've used RestSharp instead of HTTP Request because the HTTP Request wasn't working properly with their API). Thank you for your help, Dave.